# Is there any way to improve UIView beginAnimations/commitAnimations performance?

Tags: performance, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiview, core-animation

I am resizing a control via

```
[UIView beginAnimations]
[self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5f, 0.5f)];
[UIView commitAnimations]
```

The animation looks beautiful on the iPhone simulator but on my 2G test device it is unbearably slow and choppy.  How can I improve the animation on an older iPhone?  Or do I have to disable animated transitions on older devices? Thanks.

Comment: What is that control you are resizing? What does the subViews/subLayers hierarchy look like?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  The control has some subviews that do custom drawing/fills with CGPathAddArc.  Which reminds me that the arcs are rendered somewhat differently on the simulator vs. the actual device.  Any clues there what's slowing down my poor old 2G iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My problem was too many non-opaque UIViews on the screen.  I radically reduced the number through some redesign and it is very zippy now.

Comment: This is a perfect example of "doing it the first time may not be the best way".  I always get something working and go back to redesign -- hoping to improve it.  Good Job -- I am so glad you did not blame the frameworks.  You worked to improve your design!